# Bibtex cannot open .aux file

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to run bibtex on  springers latex template  https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

```
pdflatex sn-article.tex
bibtex8.exe sn-article.tex
bibtex8: security risk: running with elevated privileges
I couldn't open file name `sn-article.tex.aux'
(That was a fatal error)
```

I've also tried bibtex8.exe sn-article.aux  but that just leads to broken references.

Comment: Please clarify what's entailed by "that just leads to broken references".

Comment: @Mico it means that references that are supposed to appear as numbers e.g. [1], [2],  etc appear as [??}

Comment: After running BibTeX successfully, one must still run LaTeX twice more.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the filename extensions. Just type `pdflatex sn-article` and `bibtex8 sn-article`.

BibTeX doesn't need to look inside the .tex file. Instead, it has to look inside the aux file and find items such as (a) the bibliography style that's supposed to be used and (b) the bibliographic items that have been `\cite`d.

- By incorrectly specifying `bibtex8.exe sn-article.tex`, you're actually telling BibTeX to look for the file `sn-article.tex.aux`,  which doesn't exist, causing the fatal (bibtex) error.
- By running `bibtex8 sn-article`, you're telling BibTeX to look for the file named `sn-article.aux` -- which *does* exist as long as you've run LaTeX at least once on the tex file.

Comment: Sorry why the doesn't the .aux file exist I can see the file in the file explorer.

Comment: @HaoS - Have you set File Explorer to show the filename extensions? If not, it won't show you the file `sn-article.aux`. Hence the following recommendation: Do instruct File Explroer to show the filename extensions.

Comment: Sorry disregard my last comment I misread your answer.